# Installing octopress on github pages: 404

Tags: github, github-pages, octopress

I'm trying to install octopress to my github pages repo, I'm not sure if I've pushed the correct branch to github. I'm currently getting a 404

Which branch does octopress use to publish the blog?

https://github.com/timini/timini.github.io/tree/source/source

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your repository is a user repository, so you sources MUST be in **master** branch.

[Doc here](https://help.github.com/articles/user-organization-and-project-pages#user--organization-pages)